# How to convert text into sound in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

How to convert some code of strings to a sound and play it in the same code in python ??

get the strings of code and convert it to sound and listen to it in the code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this article](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) on writing good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time, vlc

def Sound(sound):
    vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
    media = vlc_instance.media_new(sound)
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    time.sleep(duration)
```